# What is it called when you have a file whose entire functionality is imported from different classes in different files?

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I have 3 command files: cmdA.py, cmdB.py, and cmdC.py that all contain a corresponding class with functions.

cmdA.py has a class called cmdA which contains a handful of functions.

```
#cmdA.py

class cmdA:
        def parse_cmdA:
            #code

        def union_cmdA:
            #code

        def read_cmdA:
            #code

        def write_cmdA:
            #code
```

The same formatting applies to cmdB.py and cmdC.py

I have 2 device files whose functionalities will consist of a combination of those command files.

device1.py imports cmdA and cmdC giving it its unique functionality.

device2.py imports cmdA and cmdB to give it it's unique functionality.

```
#device1.py

from cmdA import cmdA
from cmdC import cmdC

class device1:
        def __init__(<params>):
            containMethods(self,cmdA(self))
            contianMethods(self, cmdC(self))
```

When testing device1, it will only accept and run commands from cmdA and cmdC. It will not accept and run commands from cmdB. The same concept applies to device2.

What is this system called?

I like this idea of defining specific functionalities within it's own class files so that I can create a variety of devices that can share certain functions without me having to redefine those functions multiple times. I just don't know the technical term for it.

Comment: ... ["Composition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), maybe? But that would apply even if you had written all of your code in a single file.

Comment: I am not sure that there is a single term for this specific situation...

Comment: Yeesh. That `containMethods` thing is going to be pretty awkward and confusing. For example, overriding won't work. This seems more like a case for mixin inheritance, or at least assigning those methods on the class instead of the instance.

Comment: Where is this `containMethods` defined? This looks like a modified [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

Comment: @EricDuminil 
containMethods(toObject, fromObject) - contains the methods of from-object into to-object.

toObject - the object receiving methods from fromObject
fromObject - the object giving methods to toObject